# Express/mongoose put req.body issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

On localhost this works fine, but I when I put it on the live server the put requests are not sticking to the database. Specifically with `req.body` I have to define the attribute I want to send `{points: req.body.points}`

```
update: function(req, res) {
    console.log("PUT received: " + req.body.points);
    models.Player.update({ _id: req.params.pid }, req.body, function(err, player) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error: 'Player not found.'});
        } else {
            res.json(player);
        }
    });
},
```

The only way I can get the above to work on the live server is, if I write the object to update like below. This is not good because the app updates more than just points, it may send a put to update `{player_name: req.body.player_name}` you  know what I mean.

I don't understand why `req.body` isn't working, it usually does!!

```
update: function(req, res) {
    console.log("PUT received: " + req.body.points);
    models.Player.update({ _id: req.params.pid }, {points: req.body.points}, function(err, player) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error: 'Player not found.'});
        } else {
            res.json(player);
        }
    });
},
```

**EDIT:** My quick solution was to do this, but I would rather just use the `req.body` object, whats the reason it's not working?

```
update: function(req, res) {
    var test = {
        player_name : req.body.player_name,
        player_picture : req.body.player_picture,
        bench : req.body.bench,
        points : req.body.points,
        rebounds : req.body.rebounds,
        steals : req.body.steals,
        blocks : req.body.blocks,
        fouls : req.body.fouls,
        team_id : req.body.team_id,
    }
    models.Player.update({ _id: req.params.pid }, test, function(err, player) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error: 'Player not found.'});
        } else {
            res.json(player);
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: what is the route? how did you define it?

Comment: Well the model should be fine, I mean this worked fine locally, maybe I need to check that again, I do recall making changes to the model.

The route is fine it's defined in another file, ex. `app.put('api/player/:pid', player.update)` something like that.